# Sql: hackerrank aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql

Samantha was tasked with calculating the average monthly salaries for all employees in the EMPLOYEES table, but did not realize her keyboard's key was broken until after completing the calculation. She wants your help finding the difference between her miscalculation (using salaries with any zeros removed), and the actual average salary.
Write a query calculating the amount of error (i.e.:

average monthly salaries), and round it up to the next integer.

Input Format

| columns | Types |
| --- | --- |
| ID | Integer |
| Name | string |
| Salary | Integer |

The EMPLOYEES table is described as follows:

Note: Salary is per month.

Comment: What did you try so far? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: This sounds like homework. Try before you ask. You need to show the data if you want help. I suggest that you post the table definition (CREATE TABLE) and the data as an INSERT statement to help those you want to help you.

Comment: If we wanted to do hackerrank challenges we can go on HR and do them ourselves.. I've never quite understood why people think it's acceptable to take on a challenge and then repost it on SO for someone else to do; it's plagiarism and if you then claim to someone (a prospective employer?) about your great HR ranking it's fraudulently misrepresentative of your programming skill

Comment: Hello, I would advise googling the exact thing you posted... and you would find the answer.. I copy-pasted your question and got tons of results giving me the same answer

Answer (score 1):

ROUND doesn't work since it doesn't round off to the next integer, instead use `CEIL` as shown below:

```
select ceil(avg(salary)-avg(replace(salary,0,''))) from EMPLOYEES;
```

Answer (score 0):

we can try this for the question asked:

```
select ceil(avg(salary) - 
avg(replace(salary, 0, ''))) from 
employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

MS sql server

```
SELECT
CAST(CEILING(AVG(CAST(salary AS float)) -
AVG(CAST(REPLACE(salary, 0, '') AS float))) AS int)
FROM employees
```

Answer (score 0):

its in SQL

**SELECT Ceiling(AVG(Salary) - AVG(CAST(REPLACE(Salary, '0', '') AS DECIMAL))) AS res from EMPLOYEES**

This is the right query but in hacker rank its showing wrong output result but you getting this question try this query it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on MySQL. It works:

```sql
SELECT CEIL(AVG(salary)-AVG(replace(salary,0,''))) 
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

select ceil(avg(salary)-avg(cast(trim('0' from Cast(salary as varchar)))) as INTEGER)) from Employees;

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question already has plenty of answers. It would be helpful to have a description of what your answer is adding. Also, please use code formatting.

Answer (score -1):

MS SQL:

```
select cast(CEILING(avg(cast(salary as float)) - avg(cast(replace(salary,0,'') as float)))as int) from Employees
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

[SELECT ROUND(AVG(Salary),0)-ROUND(AVG(REPLACE(Salary,0,'')),0)FROM EMPLOYEES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhZQs.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).